# Feasible Sci-fi 200-300 years away weapons?

Tags: weapons, kinetic-weapons

I am writing a book about an Oceanic planet about 1/4 the size of Earth,  under the assumption that there was a wormhole at the beginning of the 1600s on Earth, leading to two island-nations above the deep depths of Nash. As I am taking in the lower gravity, I need some suggestions/ideas for weapons that utilize the low gravity feature of Nash.

To fit with the theme, I will list what I have made up so far.

Mul_Cannon- An incredibly large circular cannon that can turn approximately fifteen degrees away from a 90-degree angle, used to launch ships into orbit/towards other planets, uses internal shielding and nuclear pressure to launch ships.

Micro-Mul- A heavy ordinance turret that launches shot similar to steel cannonballs at great speeds using immense gaseous pressure.

I might add more, as this is still in the early phases. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You're new, so I will give you some tips to edit this question and make it fit more with what we do here. : ) First, be specific, how low exactly is the gravity we have to work with?

Comment: I'm also not sure of the time period--the title is 200-300 years away weapons, but you mention the 1600s. I don't think that detail of the wormhole is necessary unless you meant it to say that people and tech of 1600s came to Nash. Even then I am not sure it is nessary.

Comment: I'm a little confused about tech level and who they would be attacking exactly--each island attacks each other? Are we talking space combat against other worlds? If so, the lower gravity won't matter. Be precise in what you ask--something SPECIFIC like: In X gravity what would be a good design of personal weaponry given a tech level of X.

Answer (score 0):

So, accounting for the lower gravity of the planet, there are a multitude of options opened up that were/aren't able-to-be-built on Earth.

**- Ring Cannon**

A large cannon, utilizing plasma and magnetic fields, could be built. These large cannons could be able to, using the plasma, fire large, magnetically-contained mortars of superheated metal.

**- Hyper Railguns**

Large Railguns, significantly larger than modern ones, with the capabilities of shooting spaceships or larger warheads with larger distances and speed. Perhaps these could be used to launch large Generation Ships into orbit?